# Is there a way to pass extra parameters to Handsontable validator functions?

Tags: handsontable

I am using Handsontable v0.35.1 which is the latest version at the time of posting this question. It is used as part of Angular 5 (Typescript) component and view.

For each cell in table, I attach a custom validator as per guidelines in [official documentation](https://docs.handsontable.com/0.35.1/demo-data-validation.html#page-registering-validator) . Code looks something like this:

```
class ValidationService {

    static myCustomColumnAValidator(value, callback) {

        var contextObject = this;
        //... validation logic
    }

    static myCustomColumnBValidator(value, callback) {
        var contextObject = this;
        //... validation logic
    }
}

var hot = new Handsontable(document.getElementById('myTableContainer'), {

  data: [ { 'ColumnA': 'Data'}, { 'ColumbB' : 'Data' } }],

  columns: [
    {
        data: 'ColumnA',
        validator: ValidationService.myCustomColumnAValidator
    },

    {
        data: 'ColumnA',
        validator: ValidationService.myCustomColumnBValidator
    }
  ]
});
```

Question is, can I pass some extra parameters to the custom validator functions (myCustomColumnAValidator and myCustomColumnBValidator) apart from the `value` and `callback` function reference? I need some extra parameters as part of validation logic.

Also note that I had to mark the custom validator functions in `ValidationService` as `static` because the context object `this` is overridden to be the `ColumnSettings` object when Handsontable calls the validation function. If this was not the case, I could initialize the ValidationService with some member variables via its constructor and use in non-static version of the same validation function using `this` which would refer to the ValidationService instance. But this does not seem to be possible because Handsontable overrides the "this" context object, which I can see by stepping through the Handsontable code which uses ValidationFunction.call(contextObject, value, callback) mechanism.

Any pointers will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this way,

```
columns: [  
  {
    data: 'ColumnA',
    validator: (value, callback, extraData = this.something) => {
      console.log(extraData);
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass whatever you want here

```
columns: [
  {
      data: 'ColumnA',
      validator: ValidationService.myCustomColumnAValidator,
      customParameter: 10
  }
]
```

And you can access it like so `this.customParameter` in the validator.

Comment: This works... but only for constant, `10` in this case... can I access current row data? Something like `customParameter: data.id` or `data.ColumnB` or something like that?

Comment: And what if I use typescript?

Answer (score 0):

Using Typescript, I was able to do the following in order to pass an additional parameter to the Handsontable column validator function so the validator can be dynamic based on this parameter. In my case, the parameter was an entire object that had many properties I needed to evaluate:

```
  columns: [
    {
        data: 'ColumnA',
        validator: (value, callback) => {
           return this.yourCustomValidatorFunction(value, callback, yourCustomParameterHere)
         }
    }
  ]
```